# MySQL update a table and select from the same table in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table of link

```
CREATE TABLE `linktable` (
`id ` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idParent` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Role` ENUM('Contacts','Expert','...') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`idChild` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idt`),
UNIQUE INDEX `UK_Parent_Child_Role` (`idParent`, `idChild`, `Role`)
)
```

I want to update this table and don’t break the unique key.
With other database I make something like this :

```
Update linktable lt1 Set lt1.Parent = :ziNew Where lt1.idParent = :ziOld
and not exists (select * from linktable lt2 where lt2.idParent = :ziNew and lt1.role = lt2.role and lt1.idChild = lt2.idChild);
```

How to make this with MySQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your same syntax for variables, you would do this with a join:

```
Update linktable lt1 left outer join
       (select *
        from linktable lt2
         where lt2.idParent = :ziNew
       ) lt2
       on lt1.role = lt2.role and lt1.idChild = lt2.idChild
    Set lt1.Parent = :ziNew
    Where lt1.Parent =:ziOld and lt2.idParent is null;
```

The problem in MySQL is that the subquery is one the same table as the `update`d table.  If it were a different table, then the original form with `not exists` would still work.